# Include the IsDeleted values when user is admin

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

I want to include the `isDeleted` values in the database to my index when the user is an admin. I used the global query filter to filter the data.

This is the code I have:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(entity.ClrType);

var propertyMethodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod("Property").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool));
var isDeleted = Expression.Call(propertyMethodInfo, param, Expression.Constant("IsDeleted"));

BinaryExpression compareExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, isDeleted, Expression.Constant(false));

var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(compareExpression, param);

builder.Entity(entity.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(lambdaExpression);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore that filter for a specific users?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes. if the user is an admin, the filter should not work

Comment: HI darwin, your answer for deleted post is $a=array(array(array(5,4,3),array(1,2,3)),array(array(20,30,40),array(50,60,70)));

foreach($a as $key=>$val){

foreach($val as $key1=>$val1){
echo "".$key." ".$key1." ".(array_sum($val1))."<br>";
}
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to add additional criteria to your global query filter and make sure it's evaluated dynamically. The technique is basically explained in the [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) example:

> **Tip**
>
> Note the use of a DbContext instance level field: _tenantId used to set the current tenant. Model-level filters will use the value from the correct context instance. I.e. The instance that is executing the query.

The essential part is to use instance field/property/method of your `DbContext`, otherwise the filter will not be dynamic.

Following that, add a field to your `DbContext`:

```
bool includeDeleted = false;
```

and modify you code to produce `p => this.includeDeleted || p.IsDeleted == false`:

```
// ...

var includeDeleted = Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(this), "includeDeleted");
var condition = Expression.OrElse(includeDeleted, compareExpression);

var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(condition, param);

builder.Entity(entity.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(lambdaExpression);
```

How you populate that field is up to you. It could be via constructor parameter / injection, public property etc.

Comment: Note this doesn't work when using EF Core 2.0.0 as the filter isn't included in the resulting query.  Using a later version fixed the problem for me.